# Alfresco Unable to upload files in share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am using Alfresco standalone community edition on Ubuntu Machine with EFS as storage. Recently facing an issue while uploading file in share as it shows "Failure:Unexpected error occurred during upload of new content".[Alfresco file upload error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsGLU.png)

So checked the Catalina logs and the below mentioned was the error.

```
 ERROR [quartz.core.ErrorLogger] [DefaultScheduler_Worker-2] Job (DEFAULT.org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean#4dc8d91c threw an exception.
 org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to update the tag scopes.]
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to update the tag scopes.
        at org.alfresco.repo.tagging.UpdateTagScopesActionExecuter.executeImpl(UpdateTagScopesActionExecuter.java:295)
        at org.alfresco.repo.action.executer.ActionExecuterAbstractBase.execute(ActionExecuterAbstractBase.java:273)
        at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.directActionExecution(ActionServiceImpl.java:856)
        at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.executeActionImpl(ActionServiceImpl.java:757)
        at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.executeAction(ActionServiceImpl.java:581)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor508.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.AlwaysProceedMethodInterceptor.invoke(AlwaysProceedMethodInterceptor.java:41)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:166)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy51.executeAction(Unknown Source)
        at org.alfresco.repo.tagging.UpdateTagScopesQuartzJob.execute(UpdateTagScopesQuartzJob.java:152)
        at org.alfresco.repo.tagging.UpdateTagScopesQuartzJob.execute(UpdateTagScopesQuartzJob.java:99)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
```

```
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.ContentIOException: 07290412 Failed to create directory for file storage: /mnt/alf_data/alf_data/contentstore/2021/8/29/22/34
        at org.alfresco.repo.content.filestore.FileContentStore.makeDirectory(FileContentStore.java:309)
        at org.alfresco.repo.content.filestore.FileContentStore.createNewFile(FileContentStore.java:255)
        at org.alfresco.repo.content.filestore.FileContentStore.createNewFile(FileContentStore.java:223)
        at org.alfresco.repo.content.filestore.FileContentStore.getWriterInternal(FileContentStore.java:505)
        at org.alfresco.repo.content.AbstractContentStore.getWriter(AbstractContentStore.java:238)
        at org.alfresco.repo.content.AbstractRoutingContentStore.getWriter(AbstractRoutingContentStore.java:365)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor510.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.SubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(SubsystemProxyFactory.java:79)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.CryptodocSubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(CryptodocSubsystemProxyFactory.java:60)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.getWriter(Unknown Source)
        at org.alfresco.repo.content.ContentServiceImpl.getWriter(ContentServiceImpl.java:523)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor509.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at net.sf.acegisecurity.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:80)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.alfresco.repo.model.ml.MLContentInterceptor.invoke(MLContentInterceptor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:166)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58.getWriter(Unknown Source)
        at org.alfresco.repo.tagging.UpdateTagScopesActionExecuter.performUpdates(UpdateTagScopesActionExecuter.java:468)
        at org.alfresco.repo.tagging.UpdateTagScopesActionExecuter.access$3(UpdateTagScopesActionExecuter.java:380)
        at org.alfresco.repo.tagging.UpdateTagScopesActionExecuter$1$1.execute(UpdateTagScopesActionExecuter.java:262)
        at org.alfresco.repo.tagging.UpdateTagScopesActionExecuter$1$1.execute(UpdateTagScopesActionExecuter.java:1)
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:450)
        at org.alfresco.repo.tagging.UpdateTagScopesActionExecuter$1.doWork(UpdateTagScopesActionExecuter.java:229)
        at org.alfresco.repo.tagging.UpdateTagScopesActionExecuter$1.doWork(UpdateTagScopesActionExecuter.java:1)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:555)
        at org.alfresco.repo.tagging.UpdateTagScopesActionExecuter.executeImpl(UpdateTagScopesActionExecuter.java:222)
        ... 25 more
```

Tried adding below settings in alfresco-global config file as suggested from web but still the error is not resolved.

```
transform.service.enabled=false
local.transform.service.enabled=false
legacy.transform.service.enabled=false
```

As per error from catalina logs,  Failed to create directory for file storage but efs volumes mounted has alfresco user permissions and it is in sudoers group.

Any ideas or suggestions would be a great help Thanks

Comment: The issue was resolved by changing efs permissions to alfresco user.

Comment: Answer yourself :) and mark as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue was due to permissions and resolved after changing the efs permissions to alfresco user.